# Test case where code fails

Tags: python

I've been trying to find the minimum steps it takes for a number to be reduced to 1 given the three following steps:

1. Divide by 2
2. Increment by 1
3. Decrease by 1

My code is as follows:

```
def answer(n):
    num = long(n)
    count = 0
    while num > 1:
        #When number is odd
        if num%2 == 1:
        #If the number obtained by increment is odd, don't increment. Instead decrease 
            if ((num+1)/2)%2 == 1:
                count += 1
                num -= 1
            else:
                num += 1
                count += 1
        num /= 2
        count += 1
    return int(count)
```

Let me know if there's a better way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The code fails for n=3. It takes 3 to 1 through 3->4->2->1 whereas 3->2->1 is shorter.

I think you should do this with a bottom up DP or memoised recursion using the recurrence:

```
answer(n) = 1 + answer (n/2) if n is even,
          = 2 + min (answer ((n+1)/2), answer((n-1)/2)) if n is odd
```

Comment: Please don't answer off-topic questions. Please review our policy on [on-topic](/help/on-topic)